# Changing a column from character type to date type produces NAs

Tags: r

I have a small dataset with less than 200 rows.

```
hiv <- data.frame(id=1:6, ENTERED.DATE=c("Mar.03.2021", "Oct.16.2020", "Oct.19.2020", "Mar.09.2021", "Mar.10.2021", "Nov.16.2020"))
```

The dates are not chronological but recorded haphazardly. The file is .xlsx . Changing the date column from character type to date type produces NAs

```r
library(readxl)
hiv <- read_xlsx("hiv.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1", col_names = TRUE, na = "NA")
#> New names:
#> * `` -> `...25`
names(hiv) <- make.names(names(hiv))
date <- as.Date(as.character(hiv$ENTERED.DATE), "%d%m%Y")
head(date)
#> [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I have read some of the solutions on stackoverflow but could not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the right date format for your data: `%d%m%Y` is **date month year**, but your data has the format **monthabb.day.year**, which would require `%h.%d.%Y`:

```r
as.Date(c("Mar.03.2021", "Oct.16.2020", "Oct.19.2020", "Mar.09.2021", "Mar.10.2021", "Nov.16.2020"), "%h.%d.%Y")
```

Or in your data frame:

```r
date <- as.Date(hiv$ENTERED.DATE, "%h.%d.%Y")
```

Output:

```
"2021-03-03" "2020-10-16" "2020-10-19" "2021-03-09" "2021-03-10" "2020-11-16"
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [R Documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.Date.html) for `as.Date` they already describe this problem and provide a solution.

First you have to use the right format for your date: `%b.%m.%Y` and then you have to set the C locale as described below:

```r
hiv <- data.frame(id=1:6, ENTERED_DATE=c("Mar.03.2021", "Oct.16.2020", "Oct.19.2020", "Mar.09.2021", "Mar.10.2021", "Nov.16.2020"))

Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","C")
#> [1] "C"

as.Date(hiv$ENTERED_DATE, "%b.%d.%Y")
#> [1] "2021-03-03" "2020-10-16" "2020-10-19" "2021-03-09" "2021-03-10"
#> [6] "2020-11-16"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>